# How to store images on other server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

We have a CMS application written in `Ruby On Rails 3` and it is using `Paperclip` to handle file uploads and `ImageMagick` to do image manipulating. It has been working great, and we are very happy.

For a new customer we want to make a deployment: the application server is in a public network and the uploaded content + the database is stored on a secured computer in their internal environment.

We have 2 main tracks right now:

### Make 2 applications from the application we have right now:

A media asset application (to be developed by us) to handle all of the uploaded files using a REST-based API. Images will represented by a GUID, and we would add functions so that the images can be scaled and cropped.

Another application to be most of the application server excluding the image scaling part and storing part. When an uploaded image is requested, it will function as an adapter to the media asset application to get all the files in the correct sizes and layouts.

**Pros:**

- We have control over what's happening
- Might be a cool application in itself

**Cons:**

- A project that might grow and be very complex
- Need to make a huge change in our current application
- Need to run several Rails applications locally while developing

### Make an OpenStack installation:

The other option is to make an `OpenStack` installation and configure `Paperclip` to use it. If we have understood correctly, `Amazon S3` is using something similar to `OpenStack` and `Paperclip` should be possible to configure against a custom installation.

**Pros:**

- Paperclip and our setup will not be affected that much

**Cons:**

- Will not be simple to run a local installation
- Might be difficult to setup OpenStack
- Very little knowledge on the product if it would fail

Any ideas, thoughts, experiences?